# Query, sort and replace DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to sort the order of a nodeList that I queried for and replace them onto the DOM but using the solution below I am getting undefined in the HTML. Does anybody know whats going on?

```
const container = elem[0].childNodes[1];
let graphs = container.querySelectorAll('visualization-container[data-graph]');

const sorted = [].slice.call(graphs).sort((a, b) => {
    const first = a.getAttribute('data-graph');
    const second = b.getAttribute('data-graph');

    return scope.visualizationsOrder[first] > scope.visualizationsOrder[second] ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(sorted); // Sorted is correct
container.replaceWith(sorted); // error here
```

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the issue https://jsfiddle.net/ejdq1xyz/

Comment: any chance you could make a minimal verifiable complete example of what your problem is?

Comment: Sure give me a few to make it on jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ejdq1xyz/

Comment: The last line in the fiddle is different to the last line in the questions code: `container.replaceWith(sorted.nodeList);`. `sorted` is an array of Nodes and has no property `nodeList`

Comment: ...here's a [full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ejdq1xyz/2/) using modern features, since you're using some already. Be aware that you're removing the `container` element.

Comment: @Andreas: I'd restore your answer. Not sure which the OP wants, so maybe make note of the difference. I was mostly just pointing out that `.apply()` isn't needed.

Comment: I actually didn't realize replaceWith replaced the container, i thought it replaced the children so appendChild is actually what I ended up using. Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: @squint I've updated my answer. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" here is, that `sorted` is an array of [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

I'm not quite sure why you want to replace the container with its sorted children...
If the container should not be removed than you have to use [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) or [`.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) instead of [`.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).

And because `sorted` is an array you have to add the nodes one by one with a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
sorted.forEach(n => container.appendChild(n));
sorted.forEach(n => container.append(n));
sorted.forEach(n => container.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", n));
```

In case of `.append()` you could also use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (ES5 version) or the ES6 [spread operator/syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) as it will also accept a set of [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)/[DOMStrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString):

```
container.append.apply(container, sorted);
container.append(...sorted);
```

```js
const order = {
  identifierOne: 4,
  identifierTwo: 3,
  identifierThree: 1,
  identifierFour: 2
};

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const graphs = container.querySelectorAll('.graph[data-graph]');

const sorted = [].slice.call(graphs).sort((a, b) => {
    const first = a.getAttribute('data-graph');
    const second = b.getAttribute('data-graph');

    return order[first] > order[second] ? 1 : -1;
});

sorted.forEach(n => container.appendChild(n));
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierOne'>4</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierTwo'>3</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierThree'>1</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierFour'>2</div>
</div>
```

If the container should be replaced than you can use [`.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) with [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)  or the [spread operator/syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
container.replaceWith.apply(container, sorted);
container.replaceWith(...sorted);
```

```js
const order = {
  identifierOne: 4,
  identifierTwo: 3,
  identifierThree: 1,
  identifierFour: 2
};

const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const graphs = container.querySelectorAll('.graph[data-graph]');

const sorted = [].slice.call(graphs).sort((a, b) => {
    const first = a.getAttribute('data-graph');
    const second = b.getAttribute('data-graph');

    return order[first] > order[second] ? 1 : -1;
});

container.replaceWith.apply(container, sorted);
//container.replaceWith(...sorted);
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierOne'>4</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierTwo'>3</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierThree'>1</div>
<div class='graph' data-graph='identifierFour'>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `container.replaceWith(...sorted)`, though `.replaceWith` isn't equivalent to `.appendChild()`.  The former removes the `container`, which I guess is what the op wants?